# Different shading under Seaborn Distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create plot with shadings which are based on this MIC(1) line.
Different shading above than beneath.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def createSkewDist(mean, sd, skew, size):

    # calculate the degrees of freedom 1 required to obtain the specific skewness statistic, derived from simulations
    loglog_slope=-2.211897875506251 
    loglog_intercept=1.002555437670879 
    df2=500
    df1 = 10**(loglog_slope*np.log10(abs(skew)) + loglog_intercept)

    # sample from F distribution
    fsample = np.sort(stats.f(df1, df2).rvs(size=size))

    # adjust the variance by scaling the distance from each point to the distribution mean by a constant, derived from simulations
    k1_slope = 0.5670830069364579
    k1_intercept = -0.09239985798819927
    k2_slope = 0.5823114978219056
    k2_intercept = -0.11748300123471256

    scaling_slope = abs(skew)*k1_slope + k1_intercept
    scaling_intercept = abs(skew)*k2_slope + k2_intercept

    scale_factor = (sd - scaling_intercept)/scaling_slope    
    new_dist = (fsample - np.mean(fsample))*scale_factor + fsample

    # flip the distribution if specified skew is negative
    if skew < 0:
        new_dist = np.mean(new_dist) - new_dist

    # adjust the distribution mean to the specified value
    final_dist = new_dist + (mean - np.mean(new_dist))

    return final_dist



desired_mean = 30
desired_skew = 1.5
desired_sd = 20

final_dist = createSkewDist(mean=desired_mean, sd=desired_sd, skew=desired_skew, size=1000000)

# inspect the plots & moments, try random sample
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))
sns.distplot(final_dist, 
             hist=False, 
             ax=ax, 
             color='darkred', 
             kde_kws=dict(linewidth=4))

l1 = ax.lines[0]


# Get the xy data from the lines so that we can shade
x1 = l1.get_xydata()[:,0]
x1[0] = 0

y1 = l1.get_xydata()[:,1]
y1[0] = 0

ax.fill_between(x1,y1, color="lemonchiffon", alpha=0.3)


ax.set_ylim(0.0001,0.03)
ax.axhline(0.002, ls="--")
ax.set_xlim(1.5, 200)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticklabels([])


trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(
    ax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_transform(), ax.transData)

ax.text(0,0.0025, "{}".format("MIC(1) = 1"), color="blue", transform=trans, 
        ha="right", va="top", fontsize = 12)



trans_2 = transforms.blended_transform_factory(
    ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_transform(), ax.transData)

ax.text(84,0, "{}".format("\n84"), color="darkred", transform=trans_2, 
        ha="center", va="top", fontsize = 12)

ax.text(1.5,0, "{}".format("\n0"), color="darkred", transform=trans_2, 
        ha="center", va="top", fontsize = 12)


ax.axvline(x = 84, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.03, ls = '--', color = 'darkred' )


ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_xticks([])

ax.spines['top'].set_color(None)
ax.spines['right'].set_color(None)
ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(2)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)
ax.set_ylabel("Concentration [mg/L]", labelpad = 80, fontsize = 15)
ax.set_xlabel("Time [h]", labelpad = 80, fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title("AUC/MIC", fontsize = 20, pad = 30)


plt.annotate("AUC/MIC", 
             xy=(18, 0.02), 
             xytext=(18, 0.03), 
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"), fontsize = 12);

;
```

That's what I have:

[image]

And that's what I'd like to have (it's done in paint, so forgive me :) ):
[image]

I was experimenting with fill_between and fill_betweenx. However, without any satisfying results. Definitely, run out of ideas. I'd really appreciate any help on this. Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fill_between` works as expected. The problem is that `color="lemonchiffon"` with `alpha=0.3` is barely visible. Try to use a brighter color and/or a higher value for `alpha`.

So, this colors the part of the graph between zero and the kde curve.

Now, to create a different coloring above and below the horizontal line, `where=` and `np.minimum` can be used in `fill_between`:

```py
pos_hline = 0.002
ax.fill_between(x1, pos_hline, y1, color="yellow", alpha=0.3, where=y1 > pos_hline)
ax.fill_between(x1, 0, np.minimum(y1, pos_hline), color="blue", alpha=0.3)
```

Without `where=y1 > pos_hline`, `fill_between` would also color the region above the curve where the curve falls below that horizontal line.

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Note that `sns.histplot` has been deprecated since Seaborn version `0.11`. To only plot the kde curve, you can use `sns.kdeplot`:

```py
sns.kdeplot(final_dist, ax=ax, color='darkred', linewidth=4)
```

Comment: Yes. It's great. Thank you a lot!